# MobileFirst 7.1 Studio - Server failed to start

Tags: mobilefirst-studio

I am using MobileFirst Studio version 7.1.0.0-MFPF-StudioP2-IF201611182214.

When trying to start the local development MobileFirst server it failed with below error.

I checked the localhost entry to point to 127.0.0.1 But still the same.

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
objc[12164]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java (0x10c1d14c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x10c2cb4e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
/Users/pragupathi/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.5.2_870856665_macosx_cocoa_x86_64/plugins/com.worklight.worklight-artifacts_7.1.0.00-20161118-2214/liberty/wlp/bin/server: line 764: 12164 Abort trap: 6           "${JAVA_CMD}" "$@"

Answer (score 2):

"Address already in use ERROR"  means the port used by the server is already in use. Stop the port being used or reboot the machine so that the port shall be released and made available to the server

Comment: Thanks. Now getting the below error.Failed to deploy application '' to MobileFirst Server: FWLSE3012E: JMX connection error. Reason: "FWLSE3012E: JMX connection 
error. Reason: "CWWKX0215E: There was a problem with the user name or password provided. The server responded with code 403 and message 
'Tunnel or SSL Forbidden'". Check the application server logs for details.". Check the application server logs for details

Comment: Your logs clearly mentions that the user name and password provided is incorrect or has a problem. Please verify the same.

Comment: Thanks, We are not changing anything in WorkLight Development Server. Just install eclipse, MobileFirst Studio, start server via eclipse, and a simple HelloWorld and try to deploy on Development Server. Its fails with imx connection problem with username and password. Its not happening all MAC machine. only in one machine. We tried uninstall and reinstalled everything.